# Handling the error when using RxJS' retry operator

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have this piece of RxJS code that sends a request for some data. If it fails, I want to be infinitely retrying the request with some delay. I am achieving this with **retry** operator. However, upon the request failing, I would like to handle the error (update a variable in my component).

I tried subscribing to **retry** operator like in this [article](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/retry-rxjs-operator-4aab1fbb4347) but I'm getting ***TS2339: Property  subscribe  does not exist on type  MonoTypeOperatorFunction*** error.

Is there any way to handle error with retry operator without using deprecated **retryWhen**?

```
  const interval = 2000;
  this.xyzService.getData()
  .pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroy$),
    retry({
      delay: interval,
      resetOnSuccess: true
    }),
    //catchError(() => {
    //  ...handling error...
    //  return EMPTY;
    //}),
    map((response) => {
      this.data = response.body;
      this.state = 'LOADED';
    }),
    delay(interval),
    repeat(),
  ).subscribe()
```

Comment: Rethrow the error in catchError.

Comment: would that work? when catchError is uncommented, the code inside it's body is not reached.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply add a `tap` operator before the error hits the `retry` to handle that side logic.

```
this.xyzService.getData()
  .pipe(
    ...,
    tap({ 
      error: (err) => //handle the error local side effect
    }),
    retry({
      delay: interval,
      resetOnSuccess: true
    }),
    ...
  ).subscribe()
```

Answer (score 1):

See my example. In the `catchError`you can "handle" the error (in my case just log it to console, but you can set a local variable or what ever. But you need to rethrow the error by `throw error` so the `retry`is able to do the rest. You can throw a new error also, when you want to update the message.

I kept the example simple and it can be copy pasted to see how it works.

```
    of(undefined)
      .pipe(
        switchMap(() => {
          console.log("Trying to fetch data...");
          throw new Error();
        }),
        catchError(error => {
          console.log("Error while fetching data...");
          throw error;
        }),
        retry({ delay: 2000 })
      )
      .subscribe(() => console.log("Hello World!"));
```

The solution provided by @akotech is also working and a good one, because it is still readable that it is about error handling.